# Containarize spring booot microservices

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, containers, microservices

For a project i'm trying to put my microservices inside a container. 
Right now I can succesfully put a jar file inside a docker container and run it.
I know how docker images and containers work. But Im very new on microservices, a friend of me asked to put his spring boot microservices in a docker environment. Right now this is my plan.
Put every microservice inside 1 container , manage them with docker compose so that you can run and config them at the same time. And maybe later put some high availibility in it with docker compose scale or try something out with Docker swarm.

My question now is how do you put one service inside a container. Do you create a jar /war file from a service put that inside a container with the expose port you are working with inside your service ?

For my testjar file (a simple hello world i found online) i used this dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD /jarfiles/test.jar test.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar" , "test.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your spring boot application into docker image. Conversion of boot application can be converted using docker maven plugin or you can use docker command for this.

Using docker you need dockerfile that have the steps for creating docker image.

Once your image is ready you can run that docker image on docker engine, hence image after run will be a docker container. That is basically the virtualization.

There set of docker commands for running/creating docker images.

Install docker engine and start docker engine using

> service docker start

And then use all docker commands

Comment: I can't upvote your answer cause i am new on stack overflow , but thank you. You helped me a lot !!

Comment: You can mark it correct, right answer instead of upcast if you agreed with it.

Comment: Here yo go mate , did you have the chance to get a look at  my follow up question ?

Comment: Can you mail me your  questions again, apologies for delay.

Comment: I found the solution it was in the java code and not the docker environment .Thank you for your respond and will to help me !!